# How to specify label property for MTLComputePipelineState

Tags: ios, metal

`label` is a readonly property of `MTLComputePipelineState` so we can't change it after the creation (unlike with `MTLTexture`). But I don't see any way to even specify it during the creation of `MTLComputePipelineState`. What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably creating the `MTLComputePipelineState` using `newComputePipelineStateWithFunction:error` function or it's Swift equivalent. It doesn't have a way to populate the `label` property.

Instead, if you want to set a label, you could fill out an `MTLComputePipelineDescriptor` and use `newComputePipelineStateWithDescriptor:options:reflection:error` to create the pipeline.

To get an equivalent pipeline, you would just need to populate `computeFunction` property on the `MTLComputePipelineDescriptor` with an `MTLFunction` that you were passing to `newComputePipelineStateWithFunction:error` and populate the `label` property with the label you want.